# Peer to peer via ip address for iOS

Tags: ios, networking, ip, p2p, wan

I have ip addresses of two different iOS Devices which are connected to Internet. Now, I want to establish a peer-to-peer connection between them.

I had done this locally with Wifi and it worked properly. But I dont know how to establish this connection with an IP address. I want that I can connect them from anywhere, so I need to connect via Ip address. Also, is this possible without developing any server? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any exact solution for this problem but one approach could be you can have two ios devices connected with a network having same public IP.
So indirectly both ios devices will be connected to the same network.

Comment: yes for the internal connectivity b/w devices you need to establish a server.

Comment: okay thanks for that...but could you give me any details regarding how to setup such a server?? n how do I connect the ios devices to the same network?

Answer (score 0):

What you had done with wifi is probably an Ad-Hoc connection.  Ad-Hoc is when you connect 2 wifi devices without any Access Point in the between.

You do not have to do that on the Internet, your devices are already connected to a network. What you need to do is to find out what their IP addresses are and provide them to eachother.

In case your iOS devices are NATed behind a router, you must forward the port which you want to use from the router to the iOS device.

Here are guides for port forwarding for all the existing routers: http://portforward.com/

Comment: No I don't. It all depends what you want to do.